# Can Access read an Excel document on Sharepoint?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-access, database, sharepoint

I know very little about how Access works and I'm just stumbling my way through this little project that is waaaaaay out of my lane.

So what I'm trying to accomplish is the creation of a database that keeps track of project information for various people. The problem I have is that we would not have a dedicated person to enter any information, so we'd have to somehow rely on the individuals to update their own stuff.

So the best solution I have right now is to create a standardized form in Excel that users will simply complete after concluding a project, and upload to a Sharepoint directory. My database that doesn't exist yet will then read the information on these excel documents and populate its tables as appropriate.

Is this something that's even possible in Access? Or is there a better way to go about doing this?

Comment: If neither the database nor the spreadsheet exist yet, why not just use one or the other, rather than try to pass back and forth between the two?

Comment: Because the end goal at the moment is to have a pretty looking web app sitting on the portal that can be queried for specific information, and it needs to be able to be self-sustaining as much as possible because there isn't anyone to maintain it after it's done.